# How to update multiple rows at one time in MySQL table between specific Id

Tags: mysql

I have a table with different fields like this:

```
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
| id | Name              | phone| Date   |
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
|    |                   |      |        |   
|    |                   |      |        |
|    |                   |      |        |
|    |                   |      |        |
|    |                   |      |        |
|    |                   |      |        |
|    |                   |      |        |          
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
```

[image]

I entered a number of phone number lines like:

```
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
| id | Name              | phone| Date   |
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
|  1 |                   |563824|        |   
|  2 |                   |525225|        |
|  3 |                   |546542|        |
|  4 |                   |464625|        |
|  5 |                   |654525|        |
|  6 |                   |849842|        |
|  7 |                   |654446|        |          
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
```

Ok now I have phone data and Id of rows. Now My problem what I try to do I need to insert multiple names in Column Name at one time. Insert this names like update to multiple rows at one time but between specific id.

example I need to update rows from Id 3 to 5 to can insert names:

```
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
| id | Name              | phone| Date   |
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
|  1 |                   |563824|        |   
|  2 |                   |525225|        |
|  3 | Ali               |546542|        |
|  4 | Ahmad             |464625|        |
|  5 | Marwan            |654525|        |
|  6 |                   |849842|        |
|  7 |                   |654446|        |          
+----+-------------------+------+--------+
```

How I can do that? Any idea to do that ?I need to insert data from MySQL (Run SQL query/queries on table)

[image]

The names are in brackets because I am converting the data from an excel file to the Mr. Data Converter example: ('Marwan'),('Ali'),('Jake').

Comment: How is the DB supposed to know that Ali is associated with id=3? You should be doing updates, e.g. `UPDATE employ SET name='Ali' WHERE id=3`.

Comment: @kmoser Hello brother, this is in case I have one name, but I want to update a large group of names at once

Comment: @kmoser Also, I can't specify the identifiers of the rows one by one. I just need to specify start and end to be updated sequentially by name list.

Comment: You need to specify the ID values for each name, you could build a *values* clause to include both the ID and Name, then join to it using a subquery or CTE as part of an update.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `WHERE condition` to specify which row you want to update.
Also, since the rows are already existing, you have to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT INTO`.

Example:

```
UPDATE employ SET name = 'Ali' WHERE id >= 3 and id <= 5;
```

This will update the name of all the rows with id between 3 and 5.

If you want to update multiple rows with specific ids, you can try this:

```
UPDATE employ SET name = 'Ali' WHERE id IN (3,4,5,8,11);
```

Comment: Hello, brother, thank you for your response first. / Brother, this is in case if we have one name, but I need to update a group of names at one time . Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Because I have a group of names, a large group, it is not possible to transfer one by one , it will take a very long time

Comment: I am trying to move full column from an Access database to a Mysql database